# How can I restore the administration menu?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, menu, restore, administration

I do not know how I did it but I am now missing my administration menu. I am using 12.04 (but with all upgrades) and GNOME FALL-BACK. Could anyone direct me on how to restore it? I have tried adding it in the edit menus GUI but it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

To force Gnome to recreate its panels with default values, enter the following commands into a terminal:

```
gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/panel (This wipes the panel’s settings)

rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel (This deletes the panel’s folders and files)

killall gnome-panel (This forces the panel to close and restart)
```

Your panel should now be back with all its menus (but of course minus any customisations). If for some reason they don’t appear immediately, a reboot should fix it.